# iOS 7 change folders' background

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm on iOS 7 and I'd like to make the folders' background transparent so I can see the wallpaper behind it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no setting to customize any aspect of how folders look or behave.

Answer (score 1):

You may have turned on `Settings > General > Accessibility > Increase Contrast` which increases the contrast for areas including Unlock Screen/Notification Center/Control Center/Dock/Folder Backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Without a jailbreak : No.

With a jailbreak : Not possible either. There is no jailbreak for iOS7 yet.